# Merge layers (SAGA) ERROR

Tags: qgis, merge, qgis-processing, saga

with QGIS 2.10 it is not possible to merge vector layers with the "Processing-Saga" tool (merge layers). The following error log comes up:

```
Algorithmus Merge layers startet...
shapes_tools "Merge Layers" -INPUT "C:\Temp\convexhull2\hull2.shp,C:\Temp\convexhull2\hull3.shp,C:\Temp\convexhull2\hull4.shp" -SRCINFO -MATCH -MERGED "C:\Temp\processing\merge.shp"
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\bin>set SAGA=C:/PROGRA~1/QGISPI~1/apps\saga
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\bin>set SAGA_MLB=C:/PROGRA~1/QGISPI~1/apps\saga\modules
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\bin>PATH=PATH;C:/PROGRA~1/QGISPI~1/apps\saga;C:/PROGRA~1/QGISPI~1/apps\saga\modules
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\bin>saga_cmd shapes_tools "Merge Layers" -INPUT "C:\Temp\convexhull2\hull2.shp,C:\Temp\convexhull2\hull3.shp,C:\Temp\convexhull2\hull4.shp" -SRCINFO -MATCH -MERGED "C:\Temp\processing\merge.shp"
ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\saga\dll\gdal_MrSID.dll
127: Die angegebene Prozedur wurde nicht gefunden.
ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\saga\dll\gdal_MrSID.dll
127: Die angegebene Prozedur wurde nicht gefunden.
library path: C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\saga\modules\shapes_tools.dll
library name: Shapes - Tools
tool name : Merge Layers
author : V.Olaya (c) 2004
Load shapes: C:\Temp\convexhull2\hull2.shp,C:\Temp\convexhull2\hull3.shp,C:\Temp\convexhull2\hull4.shp...
Parameters
Layers: 1 object (hull4)
Merged Layer: Merged Layer
Add Source Information: yes
Match Fields by Name: yes
Error: Nothing to do! Merging needs more than one input data set.
Error: executing tool [Merge Layers]
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\bin>exit
```

Comment: looking at the error : merging needs more than one input data set. Error: executing tool. It looks like your a selecting just the one layer...
Have you tried with different inputs?

Comment: I selected 4 shape files!

Comment: Could anybody try if that is a bug? I tried some other shape files with the same negative result.

Comment: https://hub.qgis.org/issues/13101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was reported and fixed in [hub.qgis.org/issues/13114](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/13114):

`It was wrongly using comma instead of semicolon to separate values`